# Стоит ли разделять запятой эпитеты "ласковые" и "солнечные"?

Tags: пунктуация

Надо было о многом поразмыслить, а этот калека с грустным голосом сбивал с толку, заставляя вспоминать ласковые солнечные пряди и доверчивый синий взгляд.

"Солнечные" в смысле золотого цвета.

Answer (score 3):

Надо было о многом поразмыслить, а этот калека с грустным голосом сбивал с толку, заставляя вспоминать **ласковые, солнечные пряди** и доверчивый синий взгляд.

Если определение имеет **переносное значение (является метафорой)**, то оно обычно однородно по отношению к другим определениям. Однородный ряд обозначает **сближенные признаки, передающие общее впечатление от предмета.**

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

Согласованные определения являются однородными:

5) если представляют собой **художественные определения:** Одни кузнечики дружно трещат, и утомителен… этот **непрестанный, кислый и сухой** звук (Т.); Его **бледно-голубые, стеклянные** глаза разбегались (Т.); Старуха закрыла **свинцовые, погасшие глаза** (М. Г.); то же при употреблении определения-прилагательного в переносном значении: **круглые, рыбьи** глаза мальчика; **тонкие, журавлиные** ноги.

Comment: Очень спорно. А *доверчивый синий взгляд* — это не художественное? Два подхода в одном предложении?

Comment: Синий взгляд - это тоже метафора со значением "взгляд синих глаз", но общей темы с определением "доверчивый"  у "синий" нет, а это и есть основной признак однородности. Даже если усмотреть эту общую тему, формально запятую во втором случае точно не поставишь. Однородные прилагательные должны быть связаны чем-то общим. Солнечный - это не только цвет солнца, но и ощущение ласки и тепла. С другой стороны, автор мог иметь в виду только золотой цвет, так что  обосновать отсутствие запятой всё-таки можно.

Comment: Только одно смущает в этом предложении: одинаковая структура  и разные знаки и интонация, отсюда и появляются вопросы. Надо бы  написать: "...ласковые, солнечные пряди и доверчивый  взгляд.синих глаз.